# JPA - error when creating a cross reference entry - violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am currently implementing user authorization for a workbench using jpa, hibernate & postgresql. I got workbench groups, which can have several permissions defined by a cross reference table.

Right now I got 3 tables where JPA looks like this:

**`Table workbench_group`** This holds all the groups

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbench_groups")
public class WorkbenchGroupEntity extends BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "workbench_group_permissions", joinColumns = 
       @JoinColumn(name = "workbench_groups_id"), inverseJoinColumns = 
       @JoinColumn(name = "workbenchgroupspermissions_id"))
    private List<WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity> workbenchGroupPermissions;
```

**`Table workbench_permissions`** This holds all the permissions

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbench_permissions")
public class WorkbenchPermissionEntity extends BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private WorkbenchPermissionEnum name;
```

**`Table workbench_group_permissions`** This is my cross-reference table

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbench_group_permissions")
public class WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity extends BasicEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private WorkbenchPermissionEntity workbenchPermission;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private WorkbenchGroupEntity workbenchGroup;
```

And here is my code to add a new entry into the cross reference table:

```
    // get existing permissions
    List<WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity> existingGroupPermissions = workbenchGroupEntity.getWorkbenchGroupPermissions();

    // get permission which should be added
    WorkbenchPermissionEntity workbenchPermissionEntity = workbenchPermissionControl.findPermissionById(permissionId);

    if(this.handleExceptionsAddPermissionToWorkbenchGroup(workbenchGroupEntity, workbenchPermissionEntity, existingGroupPermissions)){
        // create new group_permission
        WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity newWorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity = new WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity();
        newWorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity.setWorkbenchGroup(workbenchGroupEntity);
        newWorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity.setWorkbenchPermission(workbenchPermissionEntity);
        // save group to database
        existingGroupPermissions.add(newWorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity);


        // !! -> Here it throws the violates not-null constraint exception!
        workbenchGroupControl.updateWorkbenchGroup(workbenchGroupEntity);
```

When I try to create a new cross reference entry into `Table workbench_group_permissions` I get an error:

**`ERROR: null value in column "workbench_groups_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, 2017-04-10 10:40:14.064, 2017-04-10 10:40:14.064, null, null).`**

This is not true, because I debugged the code and the variable in my eclipse debugger looks like this:

`WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity[id=0,workbenchPermission=WorkbenchPermissionEntity[id=1,name=GET_WORKBENCH_GROUPS,createdAt=<null>,updatedAt=<null>],workbenchGroup=WorkbenchGroupEntity[id=2,name=testgroup2,workbenchGroupPermissions=[WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity[id=0,workbenchPermission=WorkbenchPermissionEntity[id=1,name=GET_WORKBENCH_GROUPS,createdAt=<null>,updatedAt=<null>],workbenchGroup=de.abc.model.WorkbenchGroupEntity@4c13cfb5,createdAt=<null>,updatedAt=<null>]],createdAt=2017-04-10 10:38:58.462,updatedAt=2017-04-10 10:38:58.462],createdAt=<null>,updatedAt=<null>]`

As I understood I have to set the `CascadeType.All` for the `@OneToMany` relationship and hibernate should automatically create a new entry into the cross reference table when I add the new `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` to the list and run `workbenchGroupControl.updateWorkbenchGroup(workbenchGroupEntity);`.

What am I missing here?

Also, is it possible to define the permissions in the group-entity directly instead of always pulling the reference entries? So I can do sth like `workbenchGroupEntity.getPermissions()` which will return `List<WorkbenchPermissionEntity>` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the main problem in your code is that you have a mapping mistake between `workbenchGroupEntity` and `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity`.

In fact you are mapping the relationship with `@OneTomany` in one side and with `@OneToOne` in the other side, which is not logical and is incorrect.

You need to map `workbenchGroup` property with `@ManyToOne` in your  `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` class, so it can be correctly mapped by hibernate.

**Solution:**

You should change your mapping, in your `WorkbenchGroupEntity` like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbench_groups")
public class WorkbenchGroupEntity extends BasicEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="workbenchGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity> workbenchGroupPermissions;
```

And in your `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "workbench_group_permissions")
public class WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity extends BasicEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private WorkbenchPermissionEntity workbenchPermission;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "workbench_group_permissions", joinColumns = 
       @JoinColumn(name = "workbench_groups_id"), inverseJoinColumns = 
       @JoinColumn(name = "workbenchgroupspermissions_id"))
    private WorkbenchGroupEntity workbenchGroup;
```

**Edit:**

In order to allow adding multiple permissions in your  `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` class you need to change your mapping for `WorkbenchPermissionEntity` from:

```
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private WorkbenchPermissionEntity workbenchPermission;
```

To the following:

```
@OneToMany
private List<WorkbenchPermissionEntity> workbenchPermissions;
```

And make sure you change the mapping in the other side, because it was just mapped to allow inserting only one possible entry.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! With this solution I am only able to add one permission to a group, but I need multiple ones. I can create one entry inside the table `workbench_group_permissions` , but for every additional one I get `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "workbench_group_permissions_pkey"`. I might should have mentioned that :)

Comment: complete error: `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "workbench_group_permissions_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (workbench_groups_id)=(1) already exists.`

Comment: @FelixHagspiel In that case you need to change your mapping between `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` and `WorkbenchPermissionEntity`, see my Edit.

Comment: But from the error stack you pasted, you were trying to register a `WorkbenchGroupPermissionEntity` with an existing `id` which is not allowed.

Comment: actually your answer was correct, I got the last error mentioned in my comment above because I use pgAdmin to create the initial state of the database with an superadmin workbenchgroup. Unfortunately that lead to JPA creating entries in `workbench_group_permissions` with ids that already exist because it doesnt know that the auto-icrement-value increased when wildfly is already running :/ Thank you!